# Why do I need to manage/update main thread if delegate is already being used

Tags: ios, swift

I have an async api call and I'm using the delegate pattern and assigned a protocol methods to handle what to do with the data when we receive the response from api

`didWeatherUpdate`

I implement this in a delegate. The way I understand it, This method which I use to update the UI with data from api won't fire until the async network request is done.

My question is why does the main thread is need to be explicitly told that it is an async process. if the function will not be called until the data is ready after api call is complete. My assumption is that when the data is ready the function fires then added to queue that main thread works through. It seems so extra coming from a full stack background

```
  func didWeatherUpdate(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager,_ weather: WeatherModel){
        print("\(weather.temperature) from the controller")
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString
        }
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the asynchronous task calls `didWeatherUpdate` on the main thread. It's not even guaranteed that the asynchronous task runs on a background thread. On the other hand  `DispatchQueue.main` ensures that the UI is updated on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your function

```
func didWeatherUpdate(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager,_ weather: WeatherModel){
    print("\(weather.temperature) from the controller")
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString
    }
}
```

This function is called on the background thread. The `print` line is done on that thread.

If you tried to do `self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString` as the next line without wrapping it in the `DispatchQueue` async block, then it would run immediately in the background and would cause a runtime warning as you are not allowed to update the UI in the background.

To update the UI, you need to wrap your line in a block and send it to the main queue and not wait for it. That's exactly what this does

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString
}
```

The `async` here is not telling the main queue that the data fetch was async. It's saying that you want to send the block to the main queue asynchronously and not have the background thread wait for the UI to update.  If you had a `print` line right after this, it could happen before the UI updated.

If you wanted the background thread to wait for the UI, you would use `DispatchQueue.main.sync`.

Comment: I think I'm tracking, sorry if I missing something fundamental - 

my follow up, why would this function run in the background thread if it hasn't been triggered by delegate(origin)? why would a functions logic run if it hasn't been called? is that just the default unless explicitly stated?

Comment: I don’t understand. If the delegate is not called, it won’t run. If it is called, you should expect it to be on the background or at least need to check for that