# how do i get error documentation hint in xcode

Tags: xcode

[image]

I'm watching a tutorial and a question mark shows up by the purple error message with a link straight to the docs that answers why. I'm losing what's left of my sanity trying to figure out how to turn that feature on. Does anyone know how? Latest version of Xcode btw.

Comment: Use the syntax discussed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294003/why-do-i-need-to-manage-update-main-thread-if-delegate-is-already-being-used). You **must** update the UI on the main thread. Please **read** the purple message.

Answer (score 0):

The purple message comes from Main Thread Checker. It's diagnostics tool that detects improper access to UI components at runtime.

Enable it in the scheme editor on the Diagnostics tab.

More info on diagnostics tools in Apple documentation: [Diagnosing Memory, Thread, and Crash Issues Early](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/)